# How to pass PHP variables along with a Typeahead variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have cut this down to be a simple as possible.  I create a typeahead variable that works perfectly.
but I need to pass two other variables $php_var1 and $php_var2 that are unrelated to the typeahead. The PHP variables are defined in 
start.php.  The typeahead script calls search_script.php then calls cart.php.  cart.php is were I will need the two PHP variables to 
be passed to.  Thanks in advance for any help

start.php

```
<?php
  $php_var1 = "my php variable 1";
  $php_var2 = "my php variable 2";
?>


<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    var php_var1 = <?php echo $php_var1; ?>;
    var php_var2 = <?php echo $php_var2; ?>;


    $('#my_input').typeahead({
        source: function(query, result) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "search_script.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    query: query
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    result($.map(data, function(item) {
                        return item;

                    }));
                }

            })
        },
        updater: function(item) {
            location.href = 'cart.php?shop_name=' + item
            return item
        }
    });

    });

</script>

<form action="cart.php" action="post">

<input type="text"  id="my_input" placeholder="Typeahead Search" />

</form>
```

search_script.php

```
<?php

$php_var1  = isset($_REQUEST['php_var1']) ? $_REQUEST['php_var1'] : "empty";
$php_var2  = isset($_REQUEST['php_var2']) ? $_REQUEST['php_var2'] : "empty";

$connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$request = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
$query = " SELECT * FROM all_shops WHERE p_shop_name LIKE '%".$request."%'";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$data = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$data[] = $row["p_shop_name"];
}
echo json_encode($data);

}
?>
```

cart.php

```
$php_var1  = isset($_REQUEST['php_var1']) ? $_REQUEST['php_var1'] : "empty";
$php_var2  = isset($_REQUEST['php_var2']) ? $_REQUEST['php_var2'] : "empty";

echo $php_var1;
echo $php_var2;

?>
```

Comment: Have you thought of using hidden fields

Comment: yes I did, I tried <input type="hidden"  name="php_var1" />. The value does not pass, I assume it doesn't work as the <input tag I use for the typeahead doesn't use a submit button

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around the php output in order to generate javascript strings

```
var php_var1 = "<?php echo $php_var1; ?>";
var php_var2 = "<?php echo $php_var2; ?>";
```

Comment: That would have been great, so simple, but sorry to say still didn't work

Comment: what errors are thrown in browser dev tools console?

Comment: cart.php?shop_name=RCT Estate Sales:146 GET https://public_html/jquery-2.1.0.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED
cart.php?shop_name=RCT Estate Sales:38 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null
    at cart.php?shop_name=RCT Estate Sales:38
    at cart.php?shop_name=RCT Estate Sales:46
(anonymous) @ cart.php?shop_name=RCT Estate Sales:38
(anonymous) @ cart.php?shop_name=RCT Estate Sales:46
cart.php?shop_name=RCT Estate Sales:146 GET https://public_html/jquery-2.1.0.min.js 404 ()
cart.php?shop_name=RCT Estate Sales:164 Uncaught TypeError:

Comment: Cannot set property 'value' of null
    at showPosition (cart.php?shop_name=RCT Estate Sales:164)

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow is an excellent resource, but sometimes you don't get the answer, so you need to persevere and keep trying.  I worked on this all day yesterday and just couldn't figure it out.  Woke up this AM and it came to me.  The answer is as follows.  In the typeahead script change the following line

```
location.href = 'cart.php?shop_name=' + item
```

to

```
location.href = 'cart.php?shop_name=' + item + '&php_var1=<?php echo $php_var1 ?>' + '&php_var2=<?php echo $php_var2 ?>'
```